# What does this white lego piece go to?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I was building a lego van and saw this on one of my pieces. What does it go to or what set does it come from?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is [Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with 'FOLLOW ME PACE CAR' Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb095&name=Tile%201%20x%202%20with%20Groove%20with%20%27FOLLOW%20ME%20PACE%20CAR%27%20Pattern%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%208121&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C) from set 8121.

[image: part]

[image: set]

Comment: Please stop soliciting for accepted answer votes.

Comment: @PhilB. Yeah, I should stop, but I'm just hungry for rep... and accepting correct answers is a necessary feature at SE. Hopefully I won't have to be asked again.